# Sketch: Dotted Line

Tags: sketch-app, borders

Is it possible to make a dotted line in Sketch? And by line I mean the border of an object (e.g. oval).

Using dashes the dots are not perfectly round:

[image: Example for imperfect dot]

Even though I reduced the length to the absolute minimum:

[image: Dash Settings]

Comment: Wow. this is a hell of a work around but it works! http://deanhuds.tumblr.com/post/144915763551/perfect-dotted-line-in-sketch-20

Comment: ace trick, still works in 43.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [these tips](http://www.sketchtips.info/articles/arrows-and-other-border-options) and [Sketch's Twitter](https://twitter.com/sketchapp/status/288587892186554368?lang=en) you're taking the right approach.

I'm sure I've accomplished this in the past though perhaps for my purposes I didn't have your same attention to detail, that's clearly not a circle though so I can see your frustration!

Failing the way it's supposed to work, a work around could be to make a [pattern](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/creating-patterns-in-sketch-12cc612ef09a) - not the best solution but an alternative until you figure out the issue.

Comment: the first link is dead, the tweet talks about a feature that I can't find in Sketch 50.2

Answer (score 6):

Update: just noticed the comment to the OP from @Jeremy Magid above, so I'll summarize for posterity:

You don't need the file I've provided in my answer below, (though you might find it convenient), instead:

- create a (longish) line
- set rounded ends, then set the thickness, dash, and gap to the desired values, but *multiplied by 100*. eg. Want: `5, 0.1, 10`? Set: `500, 10, 1000`
- Edit > Scale the line down to 1%
- move the line's anchors to suit, or copy/paste the style

Ref: http://deanhuds.tumblr.com/post/144915763551/perfect-dotted-line-in-sketch-20

---

'Point value dashes' were once supported, and you still can copy / paste the legacy styles from a document created in an older version of Sketch!

In recent versions of Sketch you can `Copy Style` from the dotted lines in the sketch file I've provided below, then `Paste Style` onto a line in your own document.

The lines in the document have a `dash` value of `.1`, and varying `gap`s. Colours, path and line thickness remain editable, but unfortunately, any edits to the 'dash' or 'gap' values cause the dash value to snap back to `1`. To this end, I've supplied a range of gaps :)

I found that values from `.2` to `.9` were not discernibly different from `.1`, which may have contributed to the feature being pulled.

[image: preview of dotted-line-copy-style-sketch-3.3.3]

Download [dotted-line-copy-style-sketch-3.3.3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hp7aca2bvcz0pnx/dotted-line-copy-style-sketch-3.3.3.sketch?dl=0).

This workaround is working for me in Sketch 43.2.

[image: dash settings in sketch 43.2]

If you need a particular style that I haven't provided, you can download Sketch 3.3.3 from https://www.sketchapp.com/updates/. The article linked above indicates that 'point value dashes' ceased to be available in v3.4.

Credits for the concept to:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yF55HXAyYTQ
- https://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/2379-dotted-line-styles-sketch-freebie-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

From my prior experiences; the best and less painful way to achieve what you want is to make it by hand. Draw the base rectangle then Arrange > Make grid > 1 row, and X column. If you want to draw a circular one then you'll need to use another workaround which I don't know yet to achieve perfect workflow.